# UIButton, TabBarItem and BarButtonItem always tint white when I change its default tint color

Tags: ios, ios7, uibutton

I'm writing an application with TabBars and Toolbars with buttons and I want to use my own tint color.
While I can change the tint color of the elements I create in my Storyboard, the ones that I create programmatically get stuck in a barely visible white when I try to change its default blue tint to another one. These are some examples of use:

```
// a toolbar over the keyboard, note the btnDone
var keyboardToolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44))
keyboardToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default

var btnDone: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Done, target: self, action: "textViewDone")
keyboardToolbar.setItems([btnDone], animated: true)

field.inputAccessoryView = keyboardToolbar
```

When I then change the tint color with `btnDone.tintColor = UIColor(red: 153, green: 102, blue: 51, alpha: 1)` I get the following result:
[image: Result]

You can't even see the button.  If I don't write the line above I get the system blue tint color.  And this problem extends for UITabBarItems and UIButtons.

### **UPDATE**

So after some investigation and tests I kind of figured out why this is happening.  I ran the same code with a system color (like `[UIColor brownColor]`) and surprisingly it worked! So the question now is: **Is the tint color just limited to system colors? Is there any range in the RGB colors which doesn't work as a tint color?**

Comment: You set the alpha value to 0. What did you expect the result to be?

Comment: Oh sorry @rdelmar that was a typing mistake, I'm editing the question now.  The problem's still there.

Comment: I discovered something new, check my update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RGB Values should be a fractional value ranging from 0.0f - 1.0f

so divide your values by 255.0f and it will work!

```
btnDone.tintColor = UIColor(red: 153/255.0f, green: 102/255.0f, blue: 51/255.0f, alpha: 1)
```

Now when you input values more than 1.0f i.e. 153, 102 & 51, it assumes all as 1.0f and RGB color with all having values 1.0f, is white and all with values 0.0f is black!

Answer (score 0):

Try below code I have checked this in iOS7 & i0S8. Works fine. See screenshot.

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

    UIToolbar * keyboardToolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)];

    keyboardToolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
    keyboardToolBar.translucent = NO;
    keyboardToolBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:1.0f blue:0.0f alpha:1.0f];

    [keyboardToolBar setItems: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],
                                [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:nil],
                                nil]];
    textField.inputAccessoryView = keyboardToolBar;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer works with the default blue tint color, which also does for me.  But the aim is to change the tint color to **another one**, concretely the `UIColor(red: 153, green: 102, blue: 51, alpha: 1)`, which doesn't work ( see the question pic).

Comment: this works fine. i had missed to add two lines keyboardToolBar.translucent = NO; keyboardToolBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:1.0f blue:0.0f alpha:1.0f]; Check screenshot